# Counting a ncaa basketball teams wins

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to count the wins of certain college basketball teams, I have a [csv file](http://www.filedropper.com/data_3) containing that data. When I run this code no matter what I have tried it always returns 0.

```
import csv

f = open("data.csv", 'r')
data = list(csv.reader(f))


def ncaa(team):
    count = 0
    for row in data:
        if row[2] == team:
            count += 1
    return count

airforce_wins = ncaa("Air force")
akron_wins = ncaa("Akron")

print(akron_wins)
```

Comment: Without knowing what is in data1.csv it might be hard for anyway to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you "1".

```
import csv

f = open("C:\\users/alex/desktop/data.csv", 'r')
data = list(csv.reader(f))


def ncaa(team):
    count = 0
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == team: #corrected index here
            count += 1
    return count

airforce_wins = ncaa("Air force")
akron_wins = ncaa("Akron")

print(akron_wins)
```

However, I don't think you are counting the wins correctly. You are counting occurrences of a row in the file but, since each team only has one row, you will always get "1" for any team. Perhaps, your wins are in another column and that's the value you need to look up when you find your team.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead before the function definition:

```
    import csv
    with open("data1.csv", 'r') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
```

I don't think using list(reader_object) is correct.

Comment: I am still receiving 0 wins.

Comment: post a sample of your data and it will be solved easily :)

Comment: your team is in the second column, you are using the wrong index. Use "if row[1] == team:" instead